# Straights - does my card have priority over card on the table?

Tags: texas-hold-em

In this scenario I want to know if it is a split pot or if my hand wins.

On the table is AKQJ10

My hand 10 2
Opponent 3 4

We both have a straight. However, do I win because I have a card (10) forming the straight, or do the the cards on the table have priority and none of our cards matter?

There is lots online about the 'top five rule' but this never seems to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

It is a split pot. The best hand that can be formed using the 5 community cards and the player's cards wins.In this case, the community cards form the nuts (I assume a flush is not in play here). Your hand or your opponent's hand don't matter here. Doesn't matter if the ten you are holding can also be part of the straight, the 5 cards on board also "belong" to your opponent and using those he can also form a straight. I assume a flush doesn't play here, so check it down, unless you want to pay extra rake.